# MYSQL Query - Unexpected result in text messaging database

Tags: mysql

On a text messaging database I have built, I am trying to return the total amount of messages a user has sent and the total number of messages a user has received. I have the following code:

```
SELECT People.Name,
SUM(Case When Recipients.RecipientID = People.ID THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Messages Received',
Count(Messages.SenderID = People.ID) AS 'Messages Sent'
FROM People JOIN Recipients, Messages
GROUP BY People.ID
ORDER BY People.ID ASC;
```

which returns unexpected results. I am just using a test database of 3 messages sent. 2 by 1 person and 1 by another person. All 3 messages were group messages sent to the other 9 people listed in the database. So I would expect one user to have 2 messages sent and 1 received, one of the users to have 1 message sent and 2 received, and the other 8 people to have 0 sent and 3 received.

What I am actually getting is the two users who have sent message(s) have 3 messages received and 54 messages sent. The other users all have 6 messages received and 54 messages sent.

The tables are set up as follows:

```
Messages (MessageID int, SenderID int, Content varchar, Type varchar, DateTime datetime)
People (ID int, Name varchar)
Recipients (RecipientID int, MessageID int)
```

Because each message was sent to 9 people, there are 9 entries for each messageID in the Recipients table, with each one responding to a recipientID (which corresponds to People.ID).

Where does my query go wrong?

Also, in a somewhat related question, what would be the best way to modify the database if I want to add Groups and then just add people ID's to groups and allow a group to be a recipient and each person that is a member of that specific group gets counted as a recipient?

Comment: Please add the table structures, the desired results and the test data so we can help you in an easier way. Your problem is that you are doing a cross join, but we need the columns to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @jynus I have Added detail on how my tables are set up. Thank you.

Comment: `People JOIN Recipients, Messages`? Joining 3 tables without a single `ON` condition?

Comment: @ypercube yeah, well i don't know what to filter out to get the desired result

Comment: `SELECT p.Name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Recipients AS r WHERE r.RecipientID=p.ID) AS MessagesReceived, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Messages AS m WHERE m.SenderID=p.ID) AS MessagesSent FROM People AS p ORDER BY p.ID ;`

Comment: @ypercube. This worked perfectly. I studied the code a bit and I believe I follow all of the logic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your SELECT clauses may not be optimal. I suspect that `Count(Messages.SenderID = People.ID)` equals the total number of rows in the result set: for each row, `Messages.SenderID = People.ID` equals either 1 or 0, and MySQL simply counts all the 1s and 0s, and it ends up with a total number of 54 (6 times 9). Try using `SUM(Messages.SenderID = People.ID)` instead.

By the same logic, I would replace `SUM(Case When Recipients.RecipientID = People.ID THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` with `SUM(Recipients.RecipientID = People.ID)`.

Comment: That is certainly not the (only) issue in the query.

Comment: This still does not fix the query, but it is a step in the right direction. When I change the query to
`SELECT People.Name,
SUM(Recipients.RecipientID = People.ID) AS 'Messages Received',
SUM(Messages.SenderID = People.ID) AS 'Messages Sent'
FROM People JOIN Recipients, Messages
GROUP BY People.ID
ORDER BY People.ID ASC;`

I now correctly get 0 messages sent for the users that sent 0 messages. However for the user that sent 2 messages, it says 36, and for the user that sent 1 message, it says 18. I must need some type of WHERE or ON statement. The messages received part was unchanged.